# Using a ' " ' in the %[] format conversion specifier

Tags: c, io, scanf

How would I use a " in the %[] format conversion specifier in C? I have tried escaping it using the backslash escape character but this doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to use %[] with fscanf (I know fgets is the right way to do it but I am **required** to use fscanf) to read a string from a file, and as it's fscanf using %[], it stops reading once it reaches a non-matching character.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
fscanf(file_pointer, " %[a-zA-Z0-9,.'! ]", destination_array);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please show an [mcve] of the *failing* code, and describe *how* it fails.

Comment: `" %[a-zA-Z0-9,.'! \"]"` should work.

Comment: *"I know fgets is the right way to do it but I am required to use fscanf"* -- why are you even bothering using `%[]` then? Just use `%Ns`. Perhaps you are required to also use `%[]`?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I don't know what %Ns does. I don't think I'm necessarily required to use %[] but it's what we've been taught to use so far

Comment: It's just `%s`, the `N` is the maximum number of chars to read, so `char arr[10]; fscanf("%9s", arr);`

Comment: Would that not stop once it reached a whitespace character as %s does?

Comment: Returning to the OP, you have not explained why you believe that placing a double-quote in the scanf format string fails.

Comment: Then `%Nc` + add the terminator... I mean, just read the man page for `fscanf`.